# How to ireate over text of legends on QGIS and change that with fields from a Shape

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, legend

I'm using 2.8.3 version of QGIS, I need change the text of legend, this is because I want to concatenate two or more fields from a Shapefile to compose this text. 
Can I iterate over text of legends on QGIS and change that with fields from a Shapefile?
If yes, what classe in QGIS python I need to use?

Comment: Just to let you know, you can only notify other users if they have posted a comment to your question. So the two users you mentioned at the top will not receive your message =)

Comment: why don't you just combine the two fields you need to concatenate into one column in the attribute table and then create your legend?

Comment: My bad, really believed that they be notified and somehow. Facebook like. The problem is that I need to sort according to a numeric field and display information from other fields together in the legend:
I have a class field of 1 to 5, these are the ones used for classification, I have a field that indicates how much area matches this class, and another indicating the percentage of each class. The label of legend would look like this:
Class 1 - 100 hectares - 25%
for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make this by writing over QML file (style settings) or shapefile, and set this for the shape.

```
#Carregando o QML
arvore = et.parse('estilo_padrao_fert.qml')
raiz =  arvore.getroot()

for categ in raiz.iter('category'):
    valor = categ.get('value')
    lbl = categ.get('label')
    if valor == "1":
        categ.set('label', lbl + " - " + str(round(area_cls1, 3)) + " ha - " + str(round(perc_cls1, 2)) + "%") 
    elif valor == "2":
        categ.set('label', lbl + " - " + str(round(area_cls2, 3)) + " ha - " + str(round(perc_cls2, 2))+ "%") 
    elif valor == "3":
        categ.set('label', lbl + " - " + str(round(area_cls3, 3)) + " ha - " + str(round(perc_cls3, 2)) + "%") 
    elif valor == "4":
        categ.set('label', lbl + " - " + str(round(area_cls4, 3)) + " ha - " + str(round(perc_cls4, 2)) + "%") 
    else:
        categ.set('label', lbl + " - " + str(round(area_cls5, 3)) + " ha - " + str(round(perc_cls5, 2)) + "%") 

arvore.write(qml_saida_adubo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply combine the fields ("") and the labels ('')

```
'Class '||"class"||'-'||"Area"||' hectares'||' - '||" percentage "|| '%'
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Sorry, I do not think I made myself clearly understood, Label in this case is the text of the Legend, also named Label in QML file by QGIS and not this type of label.